# Devextreme 3G connecting to our server, but WIFI not

Tags: android, ios, devextreme

I have created a Devextreme app, with the following connection string :

In my Shared.Config.js file I use this to connect to our server :

"local": "http://agilesoft.dyndns.org/ProsoundService/ProsoundService.svc/",
"production": "http://agilesoft.dyndns.org/ProsoundService/ProsoundService.svc/"

Now, when I use my 3g data in my office, this works fine, except for the 3g being a tad slow. When I try to connect via WIFI it does not connect at all.

How can I get both my 3G and WIFI to connect to the above address? IS there some sort of a setting on the phone, or what should I do?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Is Your Wifi connection on the same network as your server ?

When you connect with 3G, your device is not on the same network as your server. So, the resolution of the name "agilesoft.dynsdns.org" is well performed by your 3G provider.

When you connect with Wifi on the same network as your server, the name resolution is well performed by your provider but some routers redirect to their own local loopback when they detect that you are inside the network you requested. So, instead of redirecting the request on the server as it does when you're outside, the router keep it for himself.

I don't know if it's clear...

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. I understand. Is there a way to bypass this behaviour? Should I use a normal www web address to host the service instead?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The only way I know, is to modify your "host" file to make the mapping manually between the domain and your local IP. [Windows 7 – Edit the Hosts File](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/)